# Match pattern between two character strings in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using **re** module in python, and I want to match a string that is between two character strings. Let's say I have the following string:

```
aaa

XXX
bbb
aaa
bbb

XXX
```

I want to match *aaa* strings but the ones that are only inside *XXX* strings. In example above would only match the second *aaa* string, because it is inside two *XXX* string.

How could it be implemented in python?

Comment: where is the code you tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a regex allowing you to do this.

```
import re
string = """aaa
XXX
bbb
aaa
bbb

XXX
"""
regex = "(?<=XXX)(.*\s*)*(aaa)(.*\s*)*(?=XXX)"
found = re.findall(regex, string)
print(found)
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##RY2xDsMgDER3fwViMijK0rVRfoOhCygkRUoBOURKvp4aOnQ6393TOd/lneKj1vDJiYogD0ehEDcxCSmltRaMMeCcg3Y37QF3QH7zV@Nwfk4cKhz169BKI6N/M/dOwprOuDBOflxDXOy@Y18YxO@jgsxSsHOq1i8)

Regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/xFHDI3/1)

**EDIT:**
This regex will only match one time `aaa` between the two `XXX`.